# Swift label doesn't update

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel

I have a View Controller which shows a table vc as popup. When I select a row on this popup, the tvc is dismissed, a delegate method is executed and the text of a label on my original vc should be changed.
The label should be changed by calling this delegate method:

```
    func languageDidChange() {
    //Force view to load, so that languageLabel is not nil
    self.loadViewIfNeeded()
    languageLabel.text = "Scan-Language: " + LanguageTVC.language
}
```

The label text changes (If I print it out, its right), but this change is not shown on the view controller. (I have to call loadViewIfNeeded because if I dont, my label is nil.)

My didSelectRow method where I call the delegate method:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    LanguageTVC.selectedLanguageShort = languages[indexPath.row].shortName
    delegate!.languageDidChange()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I make the text-change visible?

EDIT:

I replaced my popup segue with a show segue and added a show segue from the table view cell to the original view controller in the storyboard. I removed the dismiss statement and the whole delegate. The label-changing part is now in the viewDidLoad method.

This is just a workaround, because I have a normal segue and no popup, but it is working.

Comment: Where did you call this function?

Comment: @Frankenstein I am calling it on didSelectRowAt on my Popup View, which is a table vc. In the Same method, I call Self.dismiss()

Comment: Are you calling this function in the `viewWillAppear()` method? Alternatively, you can call it in the delegate. You might also need to ensure that it's being updated on the main thread.

Comment: Is it done on main thread?

Comment: You have to remember that your rows are still on the stack. You'll need to re-load that data. Once the view appears.

Comment: Could you show your `didSelectRowAt` method here.

Comment: @Frankenstein I updated my question

Comment: Did you set your delegate to self in parent viewController ?

Comment: @Mac3n yup, everything but the screen update is working fine

Comment: You might be missing something obvious. But, I'm not able to help with this limited info. Could you maybe modify this question to actually explain what is happening and maybe I could help.

Comment: @Frankenstein I changed a few things. Hopefully, it is better now

Comment: If you could create a github repo and share the link I could take a look.